# force makefile to build sources twice

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
all: a.out b.out
.PHONY: gen_hdr1
gen_hdr1:
    #call script 1 that generates x.h
    rm a.o #try to force rebuild of a.cpp

.PHONY: gen_hdr2
gen_hdr2:
    #call script 2 that generates x.h
    rm a.o #try to force rebuild of a.cpp

b.out: gen_hdr2 a.o
    g++ -o b.out a.o

a.out: gen_hdr1 a.o
    g++ -o a.out a.o
*.o : *.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

a.cpp includex x.h

What I want to do:

1. remove a.o if exists
2. generate x.h for App A
3. compile a.cpp
4. build App A
5. remove a.o if exists
6. generate x.h for App B
7. compile a.cpp again
8. build App B

The output of running makefile is:

```
#call script 1 that generates x.h
rm -f a.o #try to force rebuild of a.cpp
g++    -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ -o a.out a.o
#call script 2 that generates x.h
rm -f a.o #try to force rebuild of a.cpp
g++ -o b.out a.o
g++: a.o: No such file or directory
g++: no input files
make: *** [b.out] Error 1
```

Basically, a.o is not found when App B is built.
How can I force the make system to rebuild it?

Comment: Have you tried making the `a.o` target phony? I.e. `.PHONY: a.o`

Comment: Yes, I replaced the general rule for ***.o : *.cpp** to **.PHONY: a.o a.o : a.cpp** ; This is what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On good solution for that kind of problem is to use a separate build objects folder, with one more subfolder per target.

So instead you'll have something like:

```
build/first/a.o: src/a.cpp gen/a.h
    # Do you stuff in here
gen/a.h:
    # Generate you .h file if needed

build/second/a.o: src/a.cpp gen/a.h
    # Same thing
```

Using this solution you'll have all your build objects in the build folder, so the clean command is somewhat simpler:

```
clean:
    rm -rf build/*
    rm -rf gen/*
    rm -rf bin/*
```

The only thing you should ensure is that directory exists prior to build, but that's not a though work to do :)

If you have to generate two version of a.h, you could use the same design (gen/first & gen/second folders).

Hope it helps, tell me if I missed something